# Boost wserialization and serialization differences

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

I have searched the internet and the Boost serialization docs and I cannot find anything explaining why there are two different libs with boost serialization.

So far I have found that wserialization depends on serialization but what exactly does it do? and why are the two libs seperate?

Comment: I don't know the answer but I suspect it has to do with `w_char` vs. `char` datatypes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`boost::wserialization` is just a wide-char oriented version of `boost::serialization`

Comment: And the reason it's separate is because MinGW for a long time did not have `wchar_t`, and making it optional was the easiest solution.

Comment: So its completely optional to include in my application?